# Using A Blog To Create A Portfolio

Tags: portfolio, startups

Not sure this is strictly on topic but it may be something that some freelancers have experienced or may know something about.

I'm used to be a freelance website /graphic designer, but I'm new to freelancing in photography and creative writing, so my portfolio is non existent at the moment.

I've designed a front end site for advertising my services, but would love to create a back end site which works like a personal journal project, where I cover many areas of my life with written blog posts, art work, photography and stories.

So this isn't a problem, until it comes to promoting such a system. There are too many unrelated categories to create a single social media presence for promotional purposes, and too many to create an individual social account for each ( considering that some will only be active fro a few months ).

An obvious solution would be to group some of the categories together and promote several of them on the same platform, but I was wondering if there was another way of promoting your work to the audience that best suits the topic of the section.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to get very clear on your target clients and the problems your photography and creative writing skills will help them solve. My recommendation is to pick one of your skills, say photography and go after clients that need that services around that skill. You can't afford to be vague about the kind of clients you want. That's the beginning of pain and confusion.

You need to go where they are ( online or offline ) and observe them talk or discuss. You need to research and find out what they value ( and will pay for ). This will help you package your services in a way that will suit them.

From your research information, it will become easier to build a website or blog that speaks to them and draws them to you.